# too many apache processes from previous dates

Tags: apache, process

I run the command "ps aux | grep apache" in my apache running web server. Today is Nov25 but there even processes from Sep23,Oct10,etc...
There are totally 10 people using this web application but the number of running apache processes(pgrep apache2 | wc -l) are 138. When I tail the access log at that specific moment, there is only one user requesting for a page in 5 seconds interval because of an ajax call.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Check the MaxRequestsPerChild config. If it's not present or it equals 0, then each php worker could last forever.

Try setting

```
MaxRequestsPerChild 500
```

for a small app. It will kill the process after it has served 500 requests. This way you shouldn't have zombie apache workers roaming around. Also, you might want to tinker with KeepAlive and KeepAliveTimeOut to make a more efficient use of spawned childs but with a low timeout and limit request to protect you from slow http attack

```
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 2
MaxKeepAliveRequests 1000
```